# Removing an option from a select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

What's wrong with this code? I want to delete an option [that is stored in a variable) from a select when the option is already selected. I receive this error from the console:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
> select.nuevaDescripcionProducto option[value=Aspiradora Industrial ]

this is what I have so far:

```
$(".formularioVenta").on("change", "select.nuevaDescripcionProducto", function() {

var nombreProducto = $(this).val();

$("select.nuevaDescripcionProducto option[value="+nombreProducto+"]").remove();
```

If anyone have any idea, please, let me know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need extra quotes for the value since there is a space in the string

```
$("select.nuevaDescripcionProducto option[value='"+nombreProducto+"']").remove();
                                             // ^^ single quotes  ^^
```

Or as alternative using filter()

```
 $("select.nuevaDescripcionProducto").children().filter((_,op)=> op.value===$(this).val()).remove()
```